# Can't link to entries or assets via a Redactor field

Tags: assets, matrix, redactor

When using a Redactor field for a section, I can’t upload assets or link to entries. I just get an empty modal with no ability to select a section or asset folder. Thoughts on what I’m doing wrong?

[image]

[UPDATED] See video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hKKKKizSfmr1-QeblzfSbQ1B3Pf6Bybv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try updating your asset indexes to see if that helps? Utilities → Asset Indexes (or Settings → Update Asset Indexes if you're on Craft 2).

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Have you created your Asset Source? The Assets section of Craft won't work at all until there is a source set-up.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor, not specifically an Asset issue, but I did re-index with no luck.

Comment: @BradBell, no console errors: https://monosnap.com/file/cWA2MeePxQDYRZMNBtGn20U7sl0eVt

Comment: @JamieWade, yes I created the Asset Source. See video above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no Craft 3.1 compatible version of the Redactor plugin. There's a branch in the Redactor plugin repository that has such a version, but that will be released only when Craft 3.1 is released as well.